# Symfony 3: Default URI path / prefix for FOSRestController

Tags: rest, symfony, fosrestbundle

I´m implementing a REST API with **symfony 3** and **FOSRestBundle**. I want all REST methods to be available under the endpoint http://tld.com/api/v1/*. So one - not elegant - solution is to provide the complete route / path as annotation:

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return View
 * @Rest\Post("/api/v1/order/{id}")
 */
public function updateAction($extId, Request $request)
{
.....
```

Adding the full route in each annotation generates redundant code. Besides that if I want to change the version of the API to v2 I have to update all methods - not that clever.

**My preferred result:**

```
/**
 * @param $id
 * @param Request $request
 * @return View
 * @Rest\Post("/order/{id}")
 */
public function updateAction($extId, Request $request)
{
.....
```

**So my question is:**
Is there a way to **define a general route prefix** like '**/api/v1**' in the FOSRestBundle config?

Thanks for every hint :)
Ciao

Comment: Why not using prefix in your routing file like other bundles? https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation